# Strange chronic foreign key constraint issue

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have a `master` and `detail` `table` on my production `SQL Server database` at my website `hoster`.  Many inserts are done daily by my `REST` services that service my `Android apps`.  The services do an insert to the `master` and then many inserts to the `detail table.`  This all works `99.999%` of the time but every once-in-a-while I start getting this:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_TTLegs_TTMaster". The conflict occurred in database
>   "SQL2008R2_797967_golfstats", table "dbo.TTMaster", column
>   'emailaddress'. The statement has been terminated. key =
>   12703032675:try again

Now I realize that this statement is saying that I am doing an `insert` in the `detail` table when there is no such `master` record.  But there is.

This problem happens four or five times a year and I have never been able to figure out what is causing it.  DB is `SQL Server 2014`.  `emailaddress` is `nvarchar 50`.

Comment: Since it's a character field and possibly a free text field, do you check for any leading or trailing spaces in the `emailaddress` field? That might be one of the causes.

Comment: I think it is a default behavior of sql server.  You defined email-address field in master table and set it as a foreign key for details table. So sql-server validates every entry in the detail table should be exist in master table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is occurring so rarely, one option is disable this foreign key and do checks using a SQL job which can run into a log table what are the records that fail this validation. Something like this:

```
SELECT D.*
FROm dbo.FK_TTLegs_TTMaster D
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TTMaster M ON M.emailadrress = D.emailadrress)
```

Thus, you temporary allow invalid data, but you are able to find out the exact record which violates the constraint.

The job can run as often as you see fit and notify you when an error occurs (e-mail etc.).

**NOTE:** Using `VARCHAR`s as `FK`s is not a good idea since comparisons may lead to trouble (depending on collation, leading or trailing blanks) and it is not performance-wise (each INSERT or UPDATE into the detail table must validate the data against the master table and strings comparisons are more costly that integer comparison).

**[EDIT]**

Above text may be useful for investigation, but I think that the real problem is the table design. If the e-mail address should be the same on master and detail, then it should be stored only in master table.

1. Remove `emailaddress` from `dbo.TTLegs_TTMaster`
2. Use a `surrogate key` to link master and detail tables, if a natural one cannot be used on `master`
3. If the `INSERT` is done from the application layer (`.NET`, `Java` etc.), it can validate it against the master table before `INSERT`
4. If the `INSERT` is done in `SQL Server` (import, `ETL` etc.), it can execute only those inserts that have a match e-mail address and report in an error log those records that fail this validation